# Why does the ordering function invert itself?

Tags: permutations

I notice in my `R` console that `x=sample(1:n); all(order(order(x)) == x)` always evaluates `TRUE`, for any `n`. Just to assure you I'm not on the wrong SE site here, I know exactly what the code means, but this still makes my brain hurt. Can anyone draw a picture or give an explanatory proof to show what's going on?

Programming background

In `R`, `sample` scrambles a sequence, sampling without replacement, and `order` gives indices such that `x[order(x)]` is ascending. `==` does element-wise comparison, returning a vector of logical values. `all` returns `TRUE` for a list that's all `TRUE` and `FALSE` if the list contains any `FALSE` elements.

Comment: Note that `order(x)[order(order(x))]` is sorted (set `z = order(x)` to see this).

Comment: A little while ago there was a great almost-correct answer with a weird proof by induction. Where did it go? I really liked it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when $x$ is a list of $n$ elements, $\text{order}(x)$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $x_{\text{order}(x)_i} \le x_{\text{order}(x)_j}$ whenever $i<j$.  (The elements of $x$, taken in the order given by $\text{order}(x)$, are non-decreasing.)  When $x$ is itself a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, this constraint uniquely defines the order function, and indeed we can say that $x_{\text{order}(x)_i}=i$.  (The elements of a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, taken in non-decreasing order, are just $1,2,\ldots,n$.)

So, in the group of permutations under the composition operator, $\text{order}(x)=x^{-1}.$  But this immediately gives the desired result:
$$
\text{order}(\text{order}(x))=\text{order}(x)^{-1}=\left(x^{-1}\right)^{-1}=x.
$$

Comment: Wait a minute. `order()` is not a member of that permutation group because it selects among many *different* permutations depending on the input. `order(1:4)` uses the identity permutation; `order(c(2,3,4,1))` uses the permutation `y ==> y[c(4, 1, 2, 3)]`.

Comment: Are you saying `order()` is not a single member of that group but rather the map from a given element to its inverse?

Comment: If I understand right, I really like the answer, but I think it would be clearer if it stated up front that it helps to view every list `x` as a way of representing the permutation `y ==> y[x]`. Do you mind if I edit to try to expand on that point, and you can roll back if I screw it up?

Answer (score -1):

any is a quantifying operator. If test whether one sequence is identic independent of order to the other. So `x=sample(1:n); any(order(order(x)) == x)` has always to be true. order() is idempotent. That is, if applied once there is no more change in the next application of order() to the sequence it is applied to.

From [order](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/order) You get the information the order() has the argument decreasing. Per default that is set to FALSE. To invert the order the command has to be

```
x=sample(1:n); order(order(x),decreasing=TRUE) == x)
```

Then the any() is obsolete. [any](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/any) implements "Are Some Values True?". So
in `x=sample(1:n); any(order(order(x)) == x)` the identity check `==` is applied elementwise on the cross of the two lists `x` and `order(order(x))` and then the complete misses are discarded in favor of the few matches.

So

`x=sample(1:n); order(order(x)) == order(x)` is TRUE always verifying the idempotence of order().

Comment: Run your code example and you'll see it's wrong. `order` is not idempotent.